# How to pass First Second and Last name to alert in onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

Well my code is pretty simple, yet i don't know how to pass the names to alert first, if i figure this out, i might be able to pass them to backend(probably)..

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Update Account Info</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="firstName">First Name </label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName">
    </div>
    <label for="secondName">Second Name </label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondName">
    </div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name </label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName">
    </div>
    <button (click)="onClick($event)" class="update-btn" id="update-btn">Update</button>
   </form>
 </div>
```

ts:

```
import { IdToken } from '@azure/msal-common';
@Component({
  selector: 'edit-profile',
  templateUrl: './edit-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-profile.component.scss']
})
export class EditProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onClick(){

}
}
```

Comment: To make it work via angular you have to define the form in an angular way. Sounds like your tutor wants you to read through the angular documentation, rather than have somebody else do your work ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reactive form check this link "https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-reactive-forms/"

`OR` Check Below code

`HTML Code`

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Update Account Info</h1>
  <form>
    <label for="firstName">First Name </label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" [(ngModel)]="formData.firstName">
    </div>
    <label for="secondName">Second Name </label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="secondName" [(ngModel)]="formData.secondName">
    </div>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name </label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" [(ngModel)]="formData.lastName">
    </div>
    <button (click)="onClick()" class="update-btn" id="update-btn">Update</button>
   </form>
 </div>
```

`TS File Code`

```
export class EditProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    public formData = {
        firstName:'',
        secondName:'',
        lastName:'',
      }
    
    constructor() { }
      ngOnInit() {}
      onClick(){
          console.log(this.formData);
      }
}
```